Extraction of elements of vector
I am optimizing a function that takes a vector of size ~300 as input. That objective function calls several other functions that each use a subset of the input vector. An example of that setup is below:
mainprog <- function(theta){
    alpha <- theta[1:20]
    beta <- theta[21:35]
    ...
    fun1(alpha)
    fun2(beta)
    ...
    return(X)
}

I do not want to have the alpha and beta hardcoded like in the example above because of elegance, maintenance, and sanity reasons. What’s a good way of defining those subvectors alpha and beta?
The only constraint that I have is that I’d like to be able to use an optimizer to optimize over theta without too much trouble. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about that?

so you basically want a list with the correct steps? num_list <- list(c(1:20), c(21:35));  func1(numlist[[1]]);  func2(numlist[[2]])

Does beta always start where alpha ends?

@RuiBarradas in this example yes.

You could write a function that defaults to the whole vector theta and provide alpha and beta arguments to subset it, and if beta isn't specified it defaults to alpha.
> mainprog <- function(theta, alpha=seq_along(theta), beta=alpha) {
+   s1 <- sqrt(theta[alpha])
+   s2 <- sqrt(theta[beta])
+   return(list(s1, s2))
+ }
> 
> mainprog(1:10)
[[1]]
 [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278

[[2]]
 [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278

> mainprog(1:10, 1:3)
[[1]]
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051

[[2]]
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051

> mainprog(1:10, 1:3, 7:10)
[[1]]
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051

[[2]]
[1] 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278

Wrong specifications would neatly yield NA.
> mainprog(1:10, 1:3, 7:13)
[[1]]
[1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051

[[2]]
[1] 2.645751 2.828427 3.000000 3.162278       NA       NA       NA


The function below has two extra arguments not in the OP's function.

fun_list is the list of functions to be called in mainprog;
end_points is a list of vectors each of them with the start and end of the vectors to extract from theta.

These two lists must be of the same length.
The function first creates and indices list with mapply/Reduce. The indices themselves are created applying operator : to the end points list with Reduce. Each end points vector is passed to this part of the code.
Then the 2nd mapply loop subsets theta and applies a function in the functions' list.
mainprog <- function(theta, fun_list, end_points) {
  inx_list <- mapply(\(x) Reduce(`:`, x), end_points)
  mapply(\(f, i, theta) {
    tt <- theta[i]
    f(tt)
  }, fun_list, inx_list, MoreArgs = list(theta = theta))
}

fun_list <- list(sqrt, sin)
vec_list <- list(c(1, 20), c(21, 35))
mainprog(1:50, fun_list, vec_list)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051 2.000000 2.236068 2.449490 2.645751 2.828427
#>  [9] 3.000000 3.162278 3.316625 3.464102 3.605551 3.741657 3.872983 4.000000
#> [17] 4.123106 4.242641 4.358899 4.472136
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1]  0.836655639 -0.008851309 -0.846220404 -0.905578362 -0.132351750
#>  [6]  0.762558450  0.956375928  0.270905788 -0.663633884 -0.988031624
#> [11] -0.404037645  0.551426681  0.999911860  0.529082686 -0.428182669

Created on 2024-07-01 with reprex v2.1.0
